# How to allow folder permission for another user in Linux?

Tags: permissions

Consider two user accounts `user1` and `user2` on one Linux machine. I want `user2` to be able to have read and write access to a folder in `user1` home directory.

So far created a group for both users and added both users

```
groupadd twousers
usermod -a -G twousers user1
usermod -a -G twousers user2
```

then changed the group and the path and changed the permission

```
chgrp twousers /home/user1/folder
chmod g+rwx /home/user1/folder
```

Unfortunately `user2` is still unable to access the folder `/home/user1/folder`. It seems to be quite simple but somehow I am lost. What am I missing?

Comment: Something often missed is the permissions on the parent directory.  It's possible that `/home/user1` has no execute permission for user2.  The simplest way to fix this would be `chmod o+x /home/user1` since I guess you don't want to change the group on the home directory you need to give everyone execute permission on it.

Comment: I swear that this exact same question was asked earlier this year but I wasn't able to locate it. Anyway, the other user can't access the directory because the `home` directory of each user is only traversable by the respective user. Rather than having the folder inside of another user's `home`, just put it in `mnt` and change the permissions in that directory or create an NFS export that only the two users can access.

Answer (score 10):

The problem you are experiencing was to expect. Indeed, you are trying to share a folder inside another user `home` folder, which, for obvious security reasons, is (and should) only be accessible to the owner (and `root`, but that's another story).

In order to solve your problem, you should create another folder, where the potential parent(s) folder(s) will have the same permissions for both users e.g. `/data/shared_folder`.

Here is a brief step-by-step example:

- Create a parent folder (not necessary but it's for the sake of the example):

  ```
   # cd /
   # mkdir data
  ```
- Create a shared subfolder:

  ```
   # cd data
   # mkdir shared_folder
  ```
- optional : at this stage you could copy the content of the future shared folder into `shared_folder`.

  ```
   # cp -p  /path/to/folder/* /data/shared_folder/
  ```
- Create a group `shared` and two users `bob` and `alice` to it:

  ```
   # groupadd shared
   # usermod -aG shared bob
   # usermod -aG shared alice
  ```
- Recursively change group folder ownership:

  ```
   # chgrp -R shared /data
  ```
- Adding reading, writing and executing (only for files already executables) permissions for the group `shared`:

  ```
   # chmod -R g+rwX /data
  ```
- `Bob` and `Alice` will now be able to do whatever they want inside the folder `shared` but as well in `data`.

Depending on your use case, you could just have one level but this example shows how the parent folder permissions can affect a folder deeper into the filesystem and allows for more scalability and granularity.

Comment: typo in your answer, no space in `groupadd`

Answer (score 0):

[Paradox's answer](/a/507588/112566) is indeed the best answer.
However I feel like it was not fully explained as to why a root folder should be created.

If you have a shared folder in `/home/user1/sharedfolder` then you need access to the folder `/home/user1` as well (which was explained). But you should notice that `/home/user1` is user/group owned by user1. user2 would need to be a part of the group user1 (or permissions of `/home/user1` need to be 751 or more specifically gives "other users" executable permissions which is not a good idea) to access `/home/user1`. Executable access to `/home/user1` is required in order to access the shared folder. Like sometimes I forget that even the command `"cd"` is a program, and if you cant `cd` into `/home/user1` as user2 then how can you access `/home/user1/sharedFolder` ?

So unless you want user2 to be able to access everything user1 has access to in their home folder then you would definitely require the use of a more "public meeting" spot rather than in the home. I mean, think about it this way you can't share something in your home without giving access to your home in the first place.

Lets say you have a secondary hard drive / mounted folder. If you want multiple users to access that, I recommend to throw it into `/mnt/mountedFolder', then have a shared group own that mountedFolder using the directions from the best answer above.

When using containers its acceptable to map `/mnt/mountedFolder` to a root folder inside the container like `/data` or `/config` and basically the user of your container would need to be apart of that shared group. Your container may create new users with different user IDs...if that user in the container creates a folder/file with its own permissions the users who had access to the `/mnt/mountedFolder` will be unable to access those folders/files unless those users are apart of the group of the containerised user group and that containerised user is creating files/folders where the group permission is `g+rwx`.

Hope this adds a better explanation for those who didn't understand after the best answer. Dealing with permissions can frustrating because it seems like it should be so simple, but there's actually a lot to consider. When you feel frustrated about permissions try not to do something silly and try to make everything have more elevated permissions than necessary... you are probably missing something.

Answer (score -3):

you must add user2 to user1 group then give read and write permission to group section of that specific folder